# Nginx + php7.1 + Vagrant

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, vagrant

Buenas he instalado homestead la ultima version que corre con php 7.1, pero realmente tengo proyecto creados en laravel 4.2 y que usan php 5.6, el problema es que cada vez que corro mi entorno en vagrant me vuelve a configurar el nginx con php 7.1 y quiero que se mantenga con 7.0 ya lo he configurado manualmente pero se vuelve a 7.1 cada vez que doy vagrant up o vagrant reload --provision. PD: los proyecto me han corrido perfectamente con php 7.0 cualquier version

Comment: Supongo que cuando iniciaste el desarrollo no utilizabas homestead. Incluso las versiones mas antiguas de Homestead utilizan PHP 7. Revisa: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead#old-versions PD: pudes intentar con la version 3.1.0

Comment: he leido tu respuesta pero si es correcto los proyectos corren bien en 7.0 pero no se como instalar las versiones anteriores de vagrant si me regalas el comando porfavor

Comment: No necesitas una version mas antigua de vagrant, necesitas una version mas antigua del box de homestead

Comment: vagrant box add laravel/homestead -–box-version 0.6.0
Solucion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifica el archivo `homestead.yaml` y en la linea donde dice `version:` cambia por:

```
version: 0.6.0
```

Ejemplo archivo `homestead.yaml`:

```
box: laravel/homestead
version: 0.6.0
ip: "192.168.20.20"
memory: 2048
cpus: 4
provider: virtualbox
```

Comment: hmmm bueno tu respuesta es correcta pero no me arregla el problema que tengo

Comment: que pasa me sigue configurando el nginx con php 7.1 y ya no existe php 7.1

Comment: ¿Ya destruiste la instancia de vagrant?

Comment: si ya lo destrui, pero continua configurandome el nginx con 7.1

Comment: sera al clonar el homestead que este configurando todavia con php7.1

Comment: He estado revisando el fuente de la provision que hace homestead. El box es el que tiene instalado el PHP y supongo que al provisionar realiza la actualización. Supongo que tendrás que agregar algunos comandos adicionales al `after.sh`

Comment: Es eso, o hacer las reparaciónes necesarias a tu codigo, lo cual recomiendo.

Answer (score 0):

He tenido el mismo problema, y he hecho lo siguiente, para eliminar el php7.1:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

y luego:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php-7.1
```

Espero haberte ayudado!